# Android architecture navigation popBackStack throws IllegalArgumentException "back stack is empty"

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

I have an app that's using the new navigation library. I've attached a listener to the NavController and here's what it looks like as I navigate through the app:

1. `main_fragment`
2. `authentication_subgraph`
3. `loading_fragment`
4. `set_username_fragment` calls `popBackStack(R.id.authentication, true)`
5. `loading_fragment` removed as a part of the pop back stack above.
6. `main_fragment`
7. `squad_fragment`

In some cases reported to me through Crashlytics I see that a call from `squad_fragment` throws an `IllegalArgumentException`, the call looks like:

```
close.setOnClickListener {
    if (isResumed) {
        findNavController().popBackStack()
    }
}
```

This should and in every test I've run simply pop `squad_fragment` and leave me with `main_fragment`, but in some cases (20 times last night) I got an exception here saying that the back stack is empty. How can this be? Anything I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE

I've been able to replicate the issue finally. This appear to happen when I navigate anywhere from `main_fragment` then background the app, do a bunch of other things, then return to the app from the recents list. It would seem that the navigation library doesn't restore the back stack? I'm using version 1.0.0-alpha02 right now. It appears that if instead of calling `popBackStack()` I call `navigateUp()` it works, but this concerns me because the way I exit my authentication subgraph currently is by calling `popBackStack(R.id.authentication, true)` in order to return to whatever fragment triggered the auth flow. This will eventually break in the same manner.

Looking at the code in NavController it appears that the back stack is saved and restored. So I don't understand why the backstack comes back as empty. Additionally, NavHostFragment appears to be backing up the NavController state as well as recovering it so I don't know why my backstack is empty.

Comment: Can you try again with `1.0.0-alpha03` and [file a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=409828) if you're still having an issue?

Comment: Will do, give me a few days of this in production as reproducing was a bit spotty.